# Question about the limit of a function

Tags: functions

While solving a problem, i managed to show that for all $x\in\mathbb R_0^+$, a function $f:\mathbb R_0^+\rightarrow \mathbb R_0^+$ satisfied the following property :

$\displaystyle \forall n\in\mathbb N_0, 2^nf\big(\frac{x}{2^n}+f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}\big)\big)=f(x+f(x))$. 
The function is also surjective (i do think this condition is somewhat useless here, but i write it here in case it is not). Based on those informations, can i deduce that the limit of $f$ around $0$ is $0$ ?
In other words : does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}+f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}\big)\big)=0$ implies $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x+f(x))=0$ ?
Thanks in advance for your tips and answers.

Comment: No, I think this is not correct. You're assuming too many things here, I think (continuity in particular). Maybe you should post the original problem and show your ideas. But don't rephrase the original problem.

Comment: is something not clear ? Could you clarify why it is not correct ? :(

Comment: It's not clear what the problem statement is, what your claim is and how you prove it. Are you claiming that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 $  ?

Comment: there are no claims. I'd like to know if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}+f\big(\frac{x}{2^n}\big)\big)=0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x+f(x))=0$ in this context

Comment: I am not sure. I find it hard to say given this information only. Also there's a $2^n$ multiplier there.

Comment: I am verry sorry :( but i can ensure you that there are no other informations regarding $f$

Comment: It's OK, somebody else might be able to answer. I am not an expert here.

Comment: thanks a lot though !